# WebRTC Start/Stop audio record during call

Tags: java, android, webrtc

Problem: During active call, I want record video in another application.

It is not possible, because my microphone is attached in app, where is active call. If I set function setAudioRecording() on false (in PeerConnection), record audio is stopping and I can use a mic in another app without release a call. 
My goal is start record audio again. Set audio recording on true doesn't work. Is there any ways how to do it, without ending current call? Thanks for some idea.

I am using google-webrtc library https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc

Comment: have u found solution?

Comment: Hello, yes we found solution. First you have to do is add permission to manifest: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

If you want use mic in another app during the active call, you have to set microphoneMute on false (audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false)).

for more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/sharing-audio-input

Comment: @Patrik Above solution is not working for my problem. I am facing this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62633876/use-microphone-in-webrtc-media-recorder-simultaneously-in-android. Help me to resolve this?